# Java - What is the fastest way for reading a file

Tags: java, string, file

I want to read a file as a string. Every line of this file contains information that I use to construct new objects.

I wonder what is the fastest way of doing that. Obviously, there are two options. The first is to read the whole file and create the objects by reading the string. The second is to read the data line by line and create a new object after every readLine(). Is there a real performance deference or I can go either way?

Comment: Test it and see.

Comment: Most sane ways of doing it will be about the same. Why does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is an object every couple of lines and it won't affect anything else after or before it I would go for the line by line approach. However, if there is parsing involved with nested objects or a more complicated file structure read it all first